# Switching visibility of text field when changing number of columns gridview

Tags: android, list, gridview, textview, switch-statement

I'm current having a problem designing an activity which can switch from a 'grid' to 'list' view. I'm using a GridView and to switch to the 'list', I set the maximum number of columns to 1. Now my problem is that when I switch to 'list' view, I want the image on the left along with some text on the right and not just an image in the center. All the data is taken from a custom class which is populated manually. The following images will demonstrate.

What I want:

[image: List]

What I have:

[image: Current]

My Code (XML and Java) is as follows:

**single_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.gridview.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
        android:columnWidth="128dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        >
    </GridView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private GridView myGrid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        myGrid.setAdapter(new myGridAdapter(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
        GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        //ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);     

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_grid:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Grid Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
                gv.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);                                
                return true;

            case R.id.action_list:
                Toast.makeText(this, "List Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                        
                gv.setNumColumns(1);                
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this? I've been reading for quite some time now and have also thought of viewSwitcher and viewFlipper but don't think that they are exactly what I'm looking for. I've also juggled with the idea of creating separate activities for each layout but then also read about the drawbacks.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option would probably be:

- Add a `TextView` in `single_item.xml`, and position it to the right of the image.
- Pass the current state of the GridView (i.e. the mode it's in) to your custom adapter.
- In the Adapter's `getView()`, depending on this state:

  - Call `setVisibility()` on the `TextView`, with either `VISIBLE` or `GONE`.
  - Update the ImageView's layoutParams, to align it to the center or right of its parent.

This does not require any duplication.

Example code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)inflate(...);
    }

    TextView tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    // Show/hide text according to ListView mode.
    tv.setVisibility(mMode == SHOW_TEXT ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    // also update imageView.getLayoutParams() according to mMode.
```

Comment: I understood and was able to code everything till calling the setVisibility methods. How would I perform the last operation? Also, the problem now is the images are at the center of the listView although the text is appearing correctly. Any ideas about this? Thanks for your time.